# Adding Legend to multipe plots created with Show function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, legend

I have a function of 2 variables - F(x,n).
I need to plot it as a fuction of x for several n's at the same axes system.
I understand I can use Show function in this way (for F(x,a)=x^n):

```
Show[Table[Plot[x^n, {x, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][n]], {n, 10}], 
 PlotRange -> {All, 10^14}]
```

But I couldn't figure out how to add lengeds using the parameter n.
I am trying to avoide writing each legend "by hand"' because I need it for different sets of n, so I want it to be generated semi-automatically: I want to set the beginng of the string while the end of the string is depaned on the n. For the example I gave here it should be "F = x^n"...
I have tried using Table with ToString, but it didn't work (maybe I put it on the wronge places inside the Show function)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
Show[Table[Plot[x^n,{x,0,100},PlotStyle->ColorData[1][n],
  PlotLegends->{"F=x^"<>ToString[n]}],{n,10}],PlotRange->{All,10^14}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply legends without `Show` like so.

Using automatic expressions

```
Plot[Evaluate[Array[{x^#} &, 10]], {x, 0, 100}, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[1], PlotRange -> {All, 10^14}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

or with custom labels: "F = x^n"

```
legend = LineLegend[
   Array[ColorData[1], 10],
   Array["F = x^" <> ToString[#] &, 10]];

Plot[Evaluate[Array[{x^#} &, 10]], {x, 0, 100},
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[1], PlotRange -> {All, 10^14},
 PlotLegends -> legend]
```